# Dynamics CRM 8.2 WebApi filter with special characters

Tags: dynamics-crm, special-characters, webapi

I'm making web api calls to Dynamics CRM OnPremise using JavaScript and I'm facing problems when I have a special character in my filter such as '&'. I'm encoding the value that is passed to the filter but nothing is retrieved and no error is triggered. Below is the filter part of my URI that I'm using for my request:

```
"?$filter=contains(name,'"+ encodeURIComponent(value)+"')"
```

And I have verified I have many records that has an "&" in the name field.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: tomorrow I can check, but usually you need to pay attention if the string contains the single quote, not & or other characters

Comment: @GuidoPreite hi, did you have time to check or not yet ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, thanks for reminding me. I checked and actually for "&" you need to encode it. I tried this example
"/api/data/v9.2/accounts?$select=name&$filter=contains(name,'"+ encodeURIComponent('&') +"')"

and it works on my instance, it returns the accounts having & in their name, but is a 9.2. I have no way to check if inside an 8.2 instance you get an error with this syntax, it is a possibility that doesn't work on 8.2

Answer (score -1):

```
var EmpName="Emp~!@#$%^&*()_+=-:"{}|<>?[]\;'.,/";
Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("employee", "?$filter=(startswith(name,'" + specialXmlCharacterEncode(EmpName) + "')));
function specialXmlCharacterEncode(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/\(/g, "%28").replace(/\)/g, "%29").replace(/\$/g, "%24").replace(/\:/g, "%3A").replace(/\~/g, "%7E").replace(/\=/g, "%3D").replace(/\-/g, "%2D").replace(/\\/g, "%5C").replace(/\//g, "%2F").replace(/\?/g, "%3F").replace(/\./g, "%2E").replace(/\,/g, "%2C").replace(/\;/g, "%3B").replace(/\*/g, "%2A").replace(/\_/g, "%5F").replace(/\&/g, "%26").replace(/\+/g, "%2B").replace(/\!/g, "%21").replace(/\#/g, "%23").replace(/\@/g, "%40").replace(/\'/g, "''");
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate how your code help solving the question.